# Reducing the activation delay on cPanel AutoSSL (Comodo)

Tags: https, cpanel, security-certificate

It's great to see more and more web hosting companies offering free SSL certificates. One of the popular options is cPanel's AutoSSL *BUT* it seems to have **the downside of taking "up to 48 hours" to activate** ([according to the docs](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Manage+AutoSSL#ManageAutoSSL-Overview)).

**Is anyone aware of a way to speed up this process?** Sometimes websites can't afford to have SSL offline for 48 hours.

(It would be great if you could perform this process on an account *prior* to it becoming "live", but I think activation requires that DNS is pointed at the domain you're activating. The proverbial chicken before the egg.)

Answer (score 1):

The proper place for this is a cpanel forum or feature request, fortunately others have done that.

This is a problem with autoSSL *at the moment*, but they are planning on having them activated on creation of an account.  This is in pre-release see https://features.cpanel.net/topic/ssl-installed-at-account-creation-time

To answer your question;

If instead of Comodo SSL tickets you switch to LetsEncrypt, they will be created instantly when the next cron job is run. The system adds the `/etc/cron.d/cpanel_autossl` cron daemon task to schedule the automatic provisioning of certificates.  It is up to you when to run it.

Or you can create them manually either in the user's cpanel or in WHM in the autoSSL page.